# V8 Memory Profiler - reporting heap size as 0 bytes (node <= v9)

Tags: node.js, memory, google-chrome-devtools, heap-memory, v8

I'm using using Chrome's "Allocation sampling" profiler.

With node >= v10, "Total JS heap size" hovers around `10 MB` as expected.

With node <= v9, it just shows `0 B`. No matter how long it runs. What's up with that?

[image]

Comment: Either it's always been a bug, or maybe something changed in the protocol and modern DevTools fail to talk to old Node. Considering that Node versions <= 10 are EOL (and even 12 is about to EOL in a couple of days, see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/), I doubt that anyone is going to investigate/debug/fix this.

Comment: Lol. That's my feeling too. Thanks. 
It's simply time to convince my team to upgrade our node version.